# I cannot set Foreign key in PHPmyadmin XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

When i need to set a field as the foreign key in a table,in PHPMyAdmin. I am not getting it set right.

There is a Parent table called 'user' which has a primary key called 'uid'.I am using the 'uid' in the child table called 'student_register' as foreign key. But while setting it as foreign key constraint through the relation view link in phpmyadmin . i am not able to see the 'user' table in the drop down list to select it and set the 'uid' as foreign key .. I have sent the screen shot to get a clear picture.
[the screenshot for the phpmyadmin child table 'student_register'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbNH2.png)

Answer (score 1):

**From the MYSQL User Guide:**

If you are facing this issue than you need to follow these basic steps:

1. Database storage engine must be `InnoDB`.
2. Your relational tables must be `InnoDB`.
3. Use `UNIQUE` reference key.
4. Reference Key can not be `NULL`.
5. `Datatype` of the both columns must be same.

**References:**

[Create Table Foreign Keys in MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

[Creating Foreign Key Relationships](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-foreign-key-relationships.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should add **index** to the column uid in table user in order to appear in the drop down list

Take the structure of table **user**, then  click the last option of the Action - **Add index** for the column uid.

Comment: Check whether the column have primary key index or not and the datatype ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue than you need to follow these basic steps:

1. First login into the phpMyAdmin
2. Then open the database
3. Then open the table where you want to apply the Foreign Key
4. Then go to the Operation Tab
5. Then go to the Table Options
6. Then check the storage engine in the table options
7. If the storage engine type is MyISAM then you can not apply the Foregin
   Key in that database because the storage engine MyISAM does not support
   foreign key constraints
8. That why you need to change the Storage Engine Type: InnoDB from the
   MyISAM
9. Then click on Go Button for apply the Changes